# Inflation linked bonds

Tags: fixed-income

In the traders jargon, when they say they are long a linker, does it mean they bought a linker so they will gain from declining inflation or the other way around?

Comment: Usually people buy linkers to benefit from *increasing* inflation.

Comment: Long a linker means they have bought the linker.